# Need to Refer to the Directory of a Content File

Tags: vb.net, directory, environment-variables

In my project I added a .docx file which will use mail merge to create letters from a table that the program creates.  At the end of all the processing, I'd like to have the file open automatically, as well as link up to the new data.  In order to do this the program needs to know where to find the .docx file.  That's why I added the file to the project and set build action to copy always.
I know where to find it while debugging, but I can't hard program that path in because it won't work when I deploy the application to my main computer.
I'm thinking there must be a variable that would refer to the directory where 'content' files are located, so that after building the project the directory reference still works.  Does anyone know this is done?

```
    Dim w As New Word.Application
    Dim Path As String = "C:\Users\lholk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RenewalLetter2\RenewalLetter2\StandardLetter.docx"
    Debug.Print(Path)
    w.Documents.Open(Path)

    w.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

```
    Dim sEXEFolder As String = IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).ToString
```

Note that you may not be able to modify files on the EXE path. It might be better to establish a known place to store your reference document.

Comment: That didn't quite work for me, but it lead me to the solution.  This is what I ended up with.

Comment: Dim Folder As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString